# OpenGL ES maximum textures not working properly?

Tags: android, 2d, libgdx

I am learning to develop games with Android using libgdx, a framework for programming in Android using OpenGL ES and on desktop with Java using LWJGL. The device I am testing on (HTC Hero) quotes a maximum texture size of 1024 and a maximum stack depth of 2. However, when I create textures at this maximum size, they will not load, instead displaying a white square where the texture should be. The textures are this size because they are packed sprite sheets, and it is preferable to keep them at this size. With regards to the stack depth, the device will also show a white square if more than 1 texture is used simultaneously, so it seems as though the maximum values given by OpenGL ES are one step above that of the device's actual performance. Can anybody help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are scales for texture in libgdx, like texture must be exponent of 2. so as you said you are running with sprites please go through once how to work with sprites in http://libgdx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/. I hope it works

Answer (score 0):

I find this question to be of value despite of its age.

In current devices going 1024x1024 is pretty much safe. But if it doesn't work on one of yours, go lower. 1 or 4 draw calls won't affect much performant wise.